# Seaborn histogram/displot subplots

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, histogram, subplot

I have a dataframe, df, which has different rates for multiple 'N' currencies over a time period.

```
date         pair       rate
2019-05-01   AUD/USD   -0.004
2019-05-01   GBP/USD    0.05
2019-05-01   USD/NOK    0.0002      
...
2020-01-01   AUD/USD   -0.025
2020-01-01   GBP/USD    0.021315
2020-01-01   USD/NOK    0.0045
```

I would like to do a loop to plot N histograms (one per pair) using Seaborn sns; adding a title name that states the pair name on each plot.

I 'can achieve the plots using a simple groupby:

```
df.groupby('pair').hist(bins=20, normed=True)
plt.show()
```

However, this doesn't give me the individual titles and I would like to add more features to the plot.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`seaborn.FaceGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) for these types of plots.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, row='pair')
g.map(sns.distplot, 'rate')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Iterate on your df selecting the slices for each unique value, make a distplot for each slice.

```
for pair in df.pair.unique():
    sns.distplot(df.loc[df.pair == pair,'rate'])
    plt.title(pair)
```

Answer (score 0):

- Directly using [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) is no longer recommended, and [`seaborn.distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) is deprecated.
- Use [`sns.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html), which is a figure-level plot.
- Also see [seaborn histplot and displot output doesn't match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68865538/7758804)
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.2`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# sample data
data = {'date': ['2019-05-01', '2019-05-01', '2019-05-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01'],
        'pair': ['AUD/USD', 'GBP/USD', 'USD/NOK', 'AUD/USD', 'GBP/USD', 'USD/NOK'],
        'rate': [-0.004, 0.05, 0.0002, -0.025, 0.021315, 0.0045]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# plot
g = sns.displot(data=df, x='rate', col='pair', common_bins=True)
```

[image]