# seaborn histplot and displot output doesn't match

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn, histogram, displot

- Histograms generated by [`seaborn.histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html#seaborn.histplot) and [`seaborn.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html#seaborn.displot) do not match.

  - Default plot for `sns.displot` is `kind='hist'`
- Tested with `python3.8.11`, `seaborn 0.11.2`, and `matplotlib 3.4.2`
- **Why do the outputs not match, and how can this be resolved?**
- The expectation is, given `bins`, the `density` of the corresponding plots should match.

  - `bins` is passed to [`numpy.histogram_bin_edges`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram_bin_edges.html#numpy.histogram_bin_edges)
- Information contained in [Visualizing distributions of data](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html) doesn't resolve the question.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# sample data: wide
dfw = sns.load_dataset("penguins", cache=False)[['bill_length_mm', 'bill_depth_mm']].dropna()

# sample data: long
dfl = dfw.melt(var_name='bill_size', value_name='vals')
```

### `seaborn.displot`

1. Ignores `'sharex': False`, though `'sharey'` works
2. Ignores `bins`

```py
fg = sns.displot(data=dfl, x='vals', col='bill_size', kde=True, stat='density', bins=12, height=4, facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': False})
plt.show()
```

[image]

3. Setting `xlim` doesn't make a difference

```py
fg = sns.displot(data=dfl, x='vals', col='bill_size', kde=True, stat='density', bins=12, height=4, facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': False})
axes = fg.axes.ravel()
axes[0].set_xlim(25, 65)
axes[1].set_xlim(13, 26)
plt.show()
```

[image]

### `seaborn.histplot`

```py
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 4))

sns.histplot(data=dfw.bill_length_mm, kde=True, stat='density', bins=12, ax=ax1)
sns.histplot(data=dfw.bill_depth_mm, kde=True, stat='density', bins=12, ax=ax2)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Update

- As suggested by [mwaskom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1533576), `common_bins=False` gets the histograms into the same shape, resolving the issues of ignoring `bins` and `sharex`. However, the `density` seems to be affected by the number of plots in the `displot`.

  - If there are 3 plots in the `displot`, then the density is 1/3 that shown in the `histplot`; for 2 plots, the density is 1/2.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- As suggested by [mwaskom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1533576) in a comment, `common_bins=False` gets the histograms into the same shape, resolving the issues of ignoring `bins` and `sharex`, and the `density` in a faceted plot is scaled by the number of data points in each facet, not the number of facets.
- The issue with `density` being split by the number of plots in `displot` is resolved by using `common_norm=False`

[image]

[image]

### Plot Code

```py
# displot
fg = sns.displot(data=dfl, x='vals', col='bill_size', kde=True, stat='density', bins=12, height=4,
                 facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': False}, common_bins=False, common_norm=False)

fg.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)
fg.fig.suptitle('Displot with common_bins & common_norm as False')
plt.show()

# histplot
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 4))

sns.histplot(data=dfw.bill_length_mm, kde=True, stat='density', bins=12, ax=ax1)
sns.histplot(data=dfw.bill_depth_mm, kde=True, stat='density', bins=12, ax=ax2)

fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)
fig.suptitle('Histplot')

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```