# How to plot histogram subplots for each group

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, histogram, displot

When I run the following code, I get 4 different histograms separated by groups. How can I achieve the same type of visualization with 4 different `sns.distplot()` also separated by their groups?

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "group": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4],
    "similarity": [0.1, 0.2, 0.35, 0.6, 0.7, 0.25, 0.15, 0.55]
})

df['similarity'].hist(by=df['group'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) from seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns

g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, col='group', col_wrap=2)
g.map(sns.histplot, 'similarity')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- `seaborn` is a high-level api for `matplotlib`, and `pandas` uses `matplotlib` as the default plotting backend.
- From `seaborn v0.11.2`, [`sns.distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) is deprecated, and, as per the **Warning** in the documentation, it is not recommended to directly use [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html).
- `sns.distplot` is replaced by the axes-level function [`sns.histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html), and the figure-level function [`sns.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html).
- Also see [seaborn histplot and displot output doesn't match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68865538/7758804)
- It is easy to produce a plot, but not necessarily to produce the correct plot, unless you are aware of the different parameter defaults for each api.

  - Note the difference between `common_bins` as `True` and `Fales`.
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.2`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

### `common_bins=False`

```py
import seaborn as sns

# plot
g = sns.displot(data=df, x='similarity', col='group', col_wrap=2, common_bins=False, height=4)
```

[image]

### `common_bins=True` (4)

- `sns.displot`, and `pandas.DataFrame.plot` with `kind='hist'` and `bins=4` produce the same plot.

```py
g = sns.displot(data=df, x='similarity', col='group', col_wrap=2, common_bins=True, bins=4, height=4)
```

[image]

```py
# reshape the dataframe to a wide format
dfp = df.pivot(columns='group', values='similarity')

axes = dfp.plot(kind='hist', subplots=True, layout=(2, 2), figsize=(9, 9), ec='k', bins=4, sharey=True)
```

[image]